# How to detect event Close window Browser (not TAB) in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

When I login to my web, i set localStorage for this site. And when I open something of my site in new tab, this site is still operate normally. And I hope when I close window browser, not a tab, it will clear cookie. I use event "beforeUnload" but if tab is refeshed or close, this will redirect to login. Can someone help me this solution ? Thank you so much

Comment: Are you able to detect/intercept Tab close? If yes can you share how?

Comment: @KshitijV97 i use this code: window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => localStorage.clear())